# JQuery UI dialog - customized close button disappears when focus is lost

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Using jQuery UI, I have created a dialog box with a customized close icon using the following CSS:

```
/* changing dialog close button */
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close
{
    border: none !important;
    background-image: url('images/icon-close-16.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

/* changing dialog close button */
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close:hover,
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close:focus 
{
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border: none !important;
    background-image: url('images/icon-close-16.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

/* hide the default "x" close image */
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close span 
{  display:none !important;  }
```

However, there are two undesired effects that are happening.

Most importantly, if I click on the text in the dialog box, the image that I am using for the close icon disappears. (It does reappear when the mouse hovers over the position, however.)

Secondly, a border initially appears around the icon despite my attempts to remove it via the styling in `.ui-dialog-titlebar-close`.

There is a live example at http://home.adelphi.edu/~stemkoski/JQuery-testing.html.

Any ideas on how to fix either of these problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would focus instead on the `.ui-icon-closethick` class in jQuery UI. A bit of inspecting shows that they use a [CSS sprite image](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png) and background positioning to load different icons.

Like so:

```
.ui-icon-closethick {
  background-image: url('http://home.adelphi.edu/~stemkoski/images/icon-close-16.png') !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/hamstu/w42Yw/1/

Comment: This code doesn't enable me to load a custom image, it just loads a different image from the default sprite.

Comment: It was the !important that I was missing. Thanks!